# How could I do the following example with Fiware-Perseo-fe

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-perseo

I am trying to execute the following example:

I have created two entities in orionCB.

- service= test
- subservice=/subtest

  ```
  {    
  "id":"sensor1",    
  "type":"sensor",    
  "id_accumulator":"accumulator1",    
  "typeEvent": 1 //can be 1 or 0    
  }

  {    
  "id":"accumulator1",    
  "type":"accumulator",    
  "used":132,    
  "free":83,    
  "total":215    
  }
  ```

The rules should be:

1.- if typeEvent is 1, the used attribute will be plus 1 and the free attribute will be less 1

2.- if typeEvent is 0, the used attribute will be less 1 and the free attribute will be plus 1

is it possible to do with perseo rule and subscription?

More information:

when the rules have been executing, the result will be:

```
-----> typeEvent:1    
{    
"id":"accumulator1",    
"type":"accumulator",    
"used":133,    
"free":82,    
"total":215,    
}

---> typeEvent:0    
{    
"id":"accumulator1",    
"type":"accumulator",    
"used":131,    
"free":84,    
"total":215    
}
```

Comment: I have written the same question in github.  

__
https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe/issues/291
__

Comment: PerseO has actions to update attribute in the CB but it typically does it using a fixed value, not an increment of an existing one... not sure how to solve this case with existing Perseo and CB functionality. Maybe with some kind of in-memory windows with values so increases/decreased are done in Perseo memory before sending the "fixed" update to CB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the context broker does not allow to increase an attribute directly.

I think you could use some win: time rule to try to manage this case, but I see that keeping the consistency in the entities “accumulator” in real time would probably be quite complex.

To solve this question using only Perseo, perhaps the key is to use a combination of rules and subscriptions that allow to increase and decrease the attributes of the accumulator entity.

1.First of all we need to subscribe Perseo to all typeEvent attribute:

POST to OrionCB_URL/v2/subscriptions:

```
   {
     “description”: “Notify Perseo when typeEvent changes”,
     “subject”: {
       “entities”: [
         {
           “idPattern”: “.*“,
           “type”: “sensor”
         }
       ],
       “condition”: {
         “attrs”: [
           “typeEvent”
         ]
       }
     },
     “notification”: {
       “http”: {
         “url”: “<perseoHost>/notices”
       },
       “attrs”: [
         “typeEvent”,
         “id”,
         “id_accumulator”
       ]
     },
     “expires”: “2019-06-30T14:00:00.00Z”
   }
```

2. Then, we now create a rule that add an attribute in the accumulator to indicate the need to update it every time a sensor changes the value of its typeEvent attribute:

POST to PERSEO_URL/rules:

```
   {
      “name”:“changeInAcumulator”,
      “text”:“select \“changeInAcumulator\” as ruleName, ev.id_accumulator? as id_accumulator, ev.typeEvent? as typeEvent from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(type=\“sensor\“)]“,
      “action”:{
         “type”:“update”,
         “parameters”:{
             “id”:“${id_accumulator}“,
             “type”:“accumulator”,
             “attributes”: [
                   {
                   “name”:“action”,
                   “value”:“${typeEvent}”
                   }
             ]
         }
      }
   }
```

3. We subscribe Perseo to the changes that occur in this new attribute ‘action’ for all accumulator type entities.

POST to OrionCB_URL/v2/subscriptions:

```
{
     “description”: “Notify Perseo when accumulator changes”,
     “subject”: {
       “entities”: [
         {
           “idPattern”: “.*“,
           “type”: “accumulator”
         }
       ],
       “condition”: {
         “attrs”: [
           “action”
         ]
       }
     },
     “notification”: {
       “http”: {
         “url”: “http://host.docker.internal:9090/notices”
       },
       “attrs”: [
         “id”,
         “free”,
         “used”,
         “action”
       ]
     },
     “expires”: “2019-06-30T14:00:00.00Z”
   }
```

4. We create a new rule in Perseo, that manage the new accumulator notifications, and modify the accumulator entity based of the value of ‘action’ attribute, that contains the last ‘typeEvent’ value changed by the first rule.

POST to PERSEO_URL/rules:

```
{
      “name”:“updateAcumulator”,
      “text”:“select \“updateAcumulator\” as ruleName, ev.id? as id, case cast(cast(ev.action?,String),float) when 1 then cast(cast(ev.free?,String),float)-1 else cast(cast(ev.free?,String),float)+1 end as free, case cast(cast(ev.action?,String),float) when 1 then cast(cast(ev.used?,String),float)+1 else cast(cast(ev.used?,String),float)-1 end as used from pattern [every ev=iotEvent(type=\“accumulator\“)]“,
      “action”:{
         “type”:“update”,
         “parameters”:{
             “id”:“${id}“,
             “type”:“accumulator”,
             “attributes”: [
                   {
                   “name”:“free”,
                   “value”:“${free}”
                   },
                   {
                   “name”:“used”,
                   “value”:“${used}”
                   } (editado)
             ]
         }
      }
   }
```

I hope I have helped with this response.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hello carlos Blanco:

Comment: Hello Carlos Blanco, I have another problem, now I use number 2 like stop accumulator, I have been finding in official documentation of EPL to control 0,1,2 values but I have not found the solution yet. Can you help me? please